# Bolding a word inside innerText

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to bold a few words inside a paragraph. So far I tried using HTML tags before realizing that doesn't work. Is there a way to do this without getting the element?

```
var text2_2 = document.createElement("p");
text2_2.className = "reasoning";
text2_2.innerText = "All vitamins are <strong>required</strong> by our ..."
```

Comment: Use `innerHTML` not `innerText`

Comment: @j08691 what a simple solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the string contains some HTML in it and to get the effect of that use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

```js
var text2_2 = document.createElement("p");
text2_2.className = "reasoning";
text2_2.innerHTML = "All vitamins are <strong>required</strong> by our ..."

document.body.appendChild(text2_2);
```

Comment: I was unaware of innerHTML. Thanks.